# summation of multiplying series with negative terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

i know the summation of $1 \times 2 + 2\times 3 + 3\times 4 = \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}3$
but this one has negative terms.
so we need to find below

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+1} (i(i+1))$$

e.g. $1\times 2 - 2\times 3 + 3\times 4 ....$

if you can share the derivation then it would be very great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $n$ is even,

\begin{align} \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1} i(i+1) &= 1(2)-(2)(3)+(3)(4)-4(5)+\ldots+(n-1)(n)-n(n+1) \\
&=2(1-3)+4(3-5)+\ldots+n(n-1-n-1)\\
&=(-2)(2+4+\ldots n)\\
&=(-4)\left(1+2 + \ldots +\frac{n}{2}\right)\end{align}

Edit:

If $n$ is even, the expression above simplifies to

$$(-4)\frac12\left(\frac{n}2 \right)\left(\frac{n}2 +1\right)=-\frac{n(n+2)}2$$

If $n$ is odd, then $n-1$ is even and the corresponding expression is

$$-\frac{(n-1)(n+1)}2+n(n+1)=(n+1)\left(n - \frac{n-1}{2} \right)=\frac{(n+1)^2}{2}$$

Comment: not sure, for n=3 it shall be 8 and n=5 it shall be 17.. its quite different with this approach. i tried with mathematical induction similar to [blex](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2400180/473415) approach above. it shall give a d.p. solvable with expression $S_(n+1)=S_n + (-1)^n(n+1)(n+2)$

Comment: Note the condition if $n$ is even for the approach that I stated. For $n$ is odd, handle the expression up to $n-1$ and then plus the final term. Notice that the solution is a constant time solution.

Comment: Yes it is similar to the one stated in prev comment with 1st sum as 2..base term

Comment: Edited the answer, note that the answer should be an even number as every single term is even. Your computation for $n=5$ could be wrong.

Comment: Ohh i am really sorry.. N=5 is 18, typo... I was more concerned about the negative signed value..

Comment: if $n$ is even, we should get a negative sign as the second term is bigger than the first.

Comment: I was talking for the final value of the series for a value of n though you are correct on your part...

Comment: For odd $n=2m-1$, the sum can be arranged as $$\begin{align}&1(2)+3(-2+4)+5(-4+6)+\cdots+n(-(n-1)+(n+1))\\&=2(1+3+5+\cdots+n)\\&=2(1+3+5+\cdots+(2m-1))\\&=2m^2\\&=2\left(\frac {n+1}2\right)^2\\&=\frac {(n+1)^2}2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sum_{n=1}^{2k} (-1)^{n} n(n+1) = \sum_{n=1}^{2k} (-1)^{n} n^{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{2k} (-1)^{n} n$

So we now evaluate each of the sum and finally add them up to get the required value!

now $\sum_{n=1}^{2k} (-1)^{n} n^{2} = k(2k+1)$,see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215840/proving-sum-limits-k-12n-1k-cdot-k2-2n1-cdot-n-for-all-n-geq)

also if we look a bit carefully to $\sum_{n=1}^{2k} (-1)^{n} n$,the value is $k$ as there will be $k$ pairs summing to 1.

so final value is $\sum_{n=1}^{2k} (-1)^{n} n^{2} = k(2k+1) + k = 2k(k+1)$

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$S_+(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n i (i+1) = 1\cdot2 + 2\cdot3 + 3\cdot4+\dots+n(n+1)$$
and
$$S_-(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i i (i+1) = 1\cdot2 - 2\cdot3 + 3\cdot4-\dots + (-1)^n n(n+1)$$

$\frac{S_+(n) - S_-(n)}{2} = 1\cdot2 + 3\cdot4 + 5\cdot6 \dots$ and can be written as
$$
\frac{S_+(n) - S_-(n)}{2} = 2\cdot2 + 4\cdot4 + 6\cdot6 + \dots + n^2 - (2+4+6+\dots+2n), \text{$n$ even}
$$
$$
\frac{S_+(n) - S_-(n)}{2} = 2\cdot2 + 4\cdot4 + 6\cdot6 + \dots + (n-1)^2 - (2+4+6+\dots+2(n-1)), \text{$n$ odd}
$$
Now, use the fact that $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 =\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^n i  = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Now rearrange to get $S_-(n)$.

Comment: yup did this..making it a d.p. solvable

Answer (score 0):

*Just another way to do it.*

Consider $$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n i(i+1)x^{n+1}$$ (notice that, because of the $i$, you can start the summations at $0$ instead of $1$) and write 
$$i(i+1)x^{i+1}=(i+2)(i+1)x^{i+1}-2ix^{i+1}-2x^{i+1}$$ that is to say
$$i(i+1)x^{i+1}=x\left(x^{i+2}\right)''-2x^2\left(x^{i}\right)'-2x\left(x^{i}\right)$$ mking $$S_n=x\left(\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i+2}\right)''-2x^2\left(\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i}\right)'-2x\left(\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i}\right)$$ Now, use $$\sum_{i=0}^n x^{i+2}=\frac{x^2 \left(x^{n+1}-1\right)}{x-1}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \sum_{i=0}^n x^{i}=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$ Compute the required derivatives to end with $$S_n=???$$ and replace $x$ by $-1$ to get the result.